# Angular 6 Material Tree - style

Tags: angular

I'm using the mat-tree component, I need to make it conform to the image below.
Does anyone know how I can do, customize rows and get in the image result?
If you can pass a StackBlitz with ideas or solution, thank you.

[theme mat-tree material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG3Vw.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: So far I have only used the angular documentation itself to bring the examples themselves.
And there is not for example how to activate that line on the left side or how to customize.